# SWT event triggered by combo list changing?

Tags: java, swt, listener

In SWT, I can find plenty of events that fire when text is typed into the combo, the user makes a selection, etc.

Are there any triggers for when the combo list gets updated, though?

E.g., if I the list is

```
['apple', 'banana']
```

and it becomes

```
['apple', 'banana', 'shoe']
```

is there any trigger for that, and if not, can I create one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SWT does not send an event if the list of items of a `Combo` or `CComb` changes.

If you use a JFace `ComboViewer`, its `IContentProvider` gets informed when the viewer's input changes through its `inputChanged()` method.

If that's not what you want, then you are free to write application code that notifies interested observers about content changes.